# PHPUnit vary mock method return value based on arguments

Tags: phpunit

Does PHPUnit not allow me to specify returns values based on the arguments passed in. The following gives a 500 error:

// mock session values

```
$container->get('session')
    ->method('get')
    ->with(SESSION_FILTER_MONTH)
    ->willReturn('2017-05');
$container->get('session')
    ->method('get')
    ->with(SESSION_FILTER_FUND)
    ->willReturn(1);
```

In my app, the following line throws the exception:

```
$fundId = $container->get('session')->get(SESSION_FILTER_MONTH); // works OK
$fundId = $container->get('session')->get(SESSION_FILTER_FUND); // breaks: should return 1 in my tests
```

However, if I only have a single method mock declaration, such as:

```
// $container->get('session')
//     ->method('get')
//     ->with(SESSION_FILTER_MONTH)
//     ->willReturn('test_return');
$container->get('session')
    ->method('get')
    ->with(SESSION_FILTER_FUND)
    ->willReturn('test_return_fund');

//...

// $fundId = $container->get('session')->get(SESSION_FILTER_MONTH);
$fundId = $container->get('session')->get(SESSION_FILTER_FUND); // works this time!
```

...then it works OK. Seems that it only takes a single method mock declaration even though I am providing a different argument with with() method - I want the return value to vary based on that.

I'm not really getting much info from the console either, it's just telling me `Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 302.` without an exception message. I've even tried wrapping the code in try..catch block but doesn't change the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `returnValueMap` to change the value that is being returned by your mock.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php

This method takes an array of which the first n values are the arguments being used and the last value is the return value.

So your mock would look like this:

```
$map = [
    [ SESSION_FILTER_MONTH, '2017-05'],
    [ SESSION_FILTER_FUND, 'test_return_fund']
];

$container->get('session')
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));
```

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track. I was getting NULLs back originally but I guess the `get` method has a second argument with a default value that I didn't know about. So I changed to `[SESSION_FILTER_MONTH, null, 'return_value'],` - just wanted to mention encase anyone else makes a similar error without realising. Working now :)